# Implementation of caption below figure does not work at all, error

Tags: floats, errors, captions

after you previously helped me this very afternoon I have an other unsolved question and my internet research doesn't lead to anything.

I want to include a simple figure (.png file) in my document, but as soon as I want to caption it, it will not compile and produces an error message (included below)

First, let me give you my preamble:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,11pt]{memoir}

% packages
\usepackage{kantlipsum}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{csquotes}
% Language
\usepackage[english]{babel}
%\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage{helvet}
\usepackage[style=numeric-comp, backend=bibtex, sorting=none]{biblatex}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{color} % \definecolor{heatred}[RGB}{170,0,0}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{color}
\usepackage{siunitx} % \SI{15e3}{\kg}, \SI{0.2}{\m\per\s}, \si{\kWh}
\usepackage{mdwlist} % compact lists: \begin{enumerate*}, \begin{itemize*}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{bm} % bold italic symbols in math mode
\usepackage{eurosym}
\usepackage{pdfpages}
\usepackage{tikz}
```

---

This is the code, where the figure is implemented in the text:

```
\begin{figure}[hb]
\centering
\includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{img/setup.png}
\caption{basic components of ABC}
\label{fig:setup}
\end{figure}
```

---

This is the ouput I receive, when the caption is not commented:

```
.98 \cleardoublepage
                      [2] (tex/00-statement-en.tex) [3] [4] (thesis.toc)
[5] (tex/01-introduction.tex [6]
Underfull \vbox (badness 6078) has occurred while \output is active [7])
(tex/02-structure-and-characteristics-of-mwt.tex [8]

LaTeX Warning: Reference `fig:setup' on page 9 undefined on input line 11.


Underfull \hbox (badness 10000) in paragraph at lines 9--16

<img/setup.png, id=90, 480.85158pt x 172.13918pt> <use img/setup.png>
! Undefined control sequence.
\@contdelim ->:

l.20 \caption{basic components of ABC}

?
```

---

When commenting \caption... the picture is included, but there is no reference below it (i.e. Figure 2).

An other strange thing is the following:
Since the figure is labeled, I want to refer to it in the text written on the same site. Example: `In Fig. \ref{fig:setup} something is shown.` at the position where I want to indicate the picture. There are no(!) other labels of figures before in this chapter. However the output of the mentioned command results in this: `In Fig. 2 something is shown`, so the label count starts with number 2 (???, I have no idea ...). Linked to this phenomenon is the situation, that if i include more labels on the very same site (and chapter and so on), the output number (so the number which is show when using `\ref{XYZ}`) does not change. ALL "labels" are referred as "2". I hope my explanation is detailed enough, if not please comment and I will do my very best to clarify it. Thank you very much!

Comment: I just tried to add a caption to a table. The same problem occurs. It won't let me caption it ...

Comment: You should start by removing auxiliary files from past runs (`.aux`, `.toc`, etc.). If that doesn't help, I would suspect a package conflict. You could isolate the problem by creating a small file with all your packages and just one captioned figure, then remove packages one at a time until the problem disappears. Or start with none and add them back one at a time.

Comment: There is another reason for the behaviour, you need to create a [minimal working example](http://www.dickimaw-books.com/latex/minexample/index.html) and post it along with the log file in our question.

Comment: Please provide complete document instead of its fragments, which will show your problem.

Comment: Thank you for your response. I will add code as soon as I am at my working computer. I appreciate your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer is as simple as it gets. I trusted in a complete preamble, but the `\usepackage{caption}` was somehow missing. Thank you again for your help and time! I appreciate it!

Answer (score 0):

Update your compiler, or find a new one. I'm not sure what you're using, but using the `pdflatex` command from pdfTeX Version Pi from the MiKTeX 2.9 Windows installer my code compiles correctly and provides a captioned image.

I literally copy-pasted your code into my text editor and it worked after the packages installed correctly. But it seems to give the wrong figure code as it says "Figure 0.1"

Edit: Not sure what that "1" is about, but that's probably something to do with your header code.

Using a random .png file I found of OfficeOnline being stupid

[image: Using a random .png file I found of OfficeOnline being stupid]

Comment: Can you explain what means *it worked after the packages installed correctly*? Are this means that you have different order of them in preamble as OP has in  his document preamble or that they are upgraded to recent version?

Comment: With the information given, the question cannot be answered right now. The reason for the crash happened earlier, not shown in the code.

Comment: @Zarko they failed installing the first time due to what I can only assume was the dodgy internet I get at work.

Comment: hopefully your tex is _not_ version pi. (as that would imply the original author had died and there will be no more changes ever).

Comment: I don't get that reference, but the exact version is:

Version 3.14159265-2.6-1.40.17.

I said "pi" because I'm lazy and it is infact the first 9 digits of pi. [Image](http://imgur.com/a/KHN2y)

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Indeed I tried to set up a new file, and the caption works there. But I do not understand why it isn't working in my original file. I have no idea, could you help me with it? Please tell me which data you need me to send.